# No data connection for 2G/3G on Xperia U

Tags: data-connection

I have a Sony Xperia U. I had some problems with 2G/3G data connection when I bought it. After some configuration, power off/power, removing and reinserting SIM, things went all right.

Now I've updated the OS and I have the same problem. I've set the APN, then activated the data connection, but I do not see the H/E/G symbol to tell that the data connection is active. I've verified, and have the data traffic for my subscription.

- How can I verify if the APN configuration is good? If there is an APN problem will I have the described behaviour?
- Is there some way to do some more troubleshooting? I read logs (with aLog) but didn't find anything?
- Is there any configuration/procedure to fix the problem?

Some update:

Network operator is French SFR (sometimes disappointing I must say).

So I managed to take a look at logs (using adb).

Main log:

```
I/ActivityManager( 1737): Starting: Intent { flg=0x18000000 cmp=com.android.phon
e/.DataTrafficSwitchDialog } from pid 1879
V/DataTrafficSwitchDialog( 1879): isDataTrafficEnabled? false
D/dalvikvm( 1879): GC_CONCURRENT freed 944K, 49% free 3585K/6983K, external 3880
K/4099K, paused 13ms+6ms
I/ActivityManager( 1737): Displayed com.android.phone/.DataTrafficSwitchDialog:
+404ms (total +13s268ms)
W/ActivityManager( 1737): Duplicate finish request for HistoryRecord{409aae38 co
m.android.phone/.DataTrafficSwitchDialog}
W/InputManagerService( 1737): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: co
m.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@40a0bc20
W/ActivityManager( 1737): Duplicate finish request for HistoryRecord{409aae38 co
m.android.phone/.DataTrafficSwitchDialog}
I/TelephonyRegistry( 1737): notifyDataConnection: state=0 isDataConnectivityPoss
ible=false reason=apnSwitched interfaceName=null networkType=3
I/TelephonyRegistry( 1737): notifyDataConnection: state=1 isDataConnectivityPoss
ible=true reason=apnSwitched interfaceName=null networkType=3
D/Tethering( 1737): gprs0 is not a tetherable iface, ignoring
V/kernel  ( 1481): [  801.811279] gprs0: attached
V/kernel  ( 1481): [  803.178894] gprs0: detached
E/Tethering( 1737): attempting to remove unknown iface (gprs0), ignoring
I/TelephonyRegistry( 1737): notifyDataConnection: state=0 isDataConnectivityPoss
ible=false reason=apnFailed interfaceName=null networkType=3
D/GTalkService( 1869): ##### Network broadcast (connected=false) type=mobile, st
ate=DISCONNECTED
D/Tethering( 1737): MasterInitialState.processMessage what=3
D/PicasaSyncManager( 2906): active network: null
I/MediaUploader( 3052): No need to wake up
D/PicasaSyncManager( 2906): background data: true
I/fb_music_like( 3071): AvailabilityChangeReceiver : Availability change receive
d. Action: android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE
I/fb_music_like( 3071): AvailabilityChangeReceiver : Network connectivity change
 received. No connectivity: true
I/fb_music_like( 3071): MusicLikeService.onCreate().
I/fb_music_like( 3071): MusicLikeService.onStart(): #1 intent=Intent { act=andro
id.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE cmp=com.sonyericsson.androidapp.fbmusiclike/.ser
vice.MusicLikeService (has extras) }, flags=2
I/fb_music_like( 3071): fireAvailabilityChanged(): available=true
I/fb_music_like( 3071): isNetworkAvailable: EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY found!
I/fb_music_like( 3071): fireAvailabilityChanged(): available=false
I/fb_music_like( 3071): Starting downloading music likes from Facebook.
E/fb_music_like( 3071): downloadMusicLikes: false -> Value false of type java.la
ng.Boolean cannot be converted to JSONObject
W/fb_music_like( 3071): Get Error Code: 0 Error message: request failed
I/fb_music_like( 3071): MusicLikeService.onDestroy().
D/dalvikvm( 3062): GC_EXPLICIT freed 31K, 47% free 2878K/5379K, external 1681K/2
129K, paused 44ms
I/touchd  ( 1503): 'ab8500_usb' is online
I/touchd  ( 1503): handling_uevent: event is 1
D/kernel  ( 1481): [  810.299896] cyttsp-spi spi9.0: chg_status_work: Set charge
r mode to reg: 0x1
D/dalvikvm( 3071): GC_EXPLICIT freed 87K, 48% free 2818K/5379K, external 1681K/2
129K, paused 54ms
```

Radio log ( logcat -b radio ):

```
D/GSM     ( 1879): [GsmDataConnection-1] DcInactiveState nothandled msg.what=6
D/GSM     ( 1879): [GsmDataConnection-1] DcDefaultState: msg.what=EVENT_DISCONNE
CT
D/GSM     ( 1879): [GsmDataConnection-1] NotifyDisconnectCompleted
D/GSM     ( 1879): [GsmDataConnection-1] msg.what=25 msg.obj=apnSwitched
D/GSM     ( 1879): [GsmDataConnection-1] clearSettings
D/GSM     ( 1879): [DataConnection] Stop poll NetStat
D/GSM     ( 1879): [DSAC DEB] trySetupData with mIsPsRestricted=false
I/GSM     ( 1879): Preferred APN:20810:20810:[ApnSettingV2] SFR, 3, 20810, wapsf
r, 195.115.25.129, , , , 8080, -1, *, IP, IP
I/GSM     ( 1879): Waiting APN set to preferred APN
D/GSM     ( 1879): [GsmDataConnectionTracker] Create from allApns : [[ApnSetting
V2] SFR, 3, 20810, wapsfr, 195.115.25.129, , , , 8080, -1, *, IP, IP]
D/GSM     ( 1879): [GsmDataConnection-1] DcInactiveState msg.what=EVENT_CONNECT
D/GSM     ( 1879): [GsmDataConnection-1] Connecting to carrier: 'SFR' APN: 'waps
fr' proxy: '195.115.25.129' port: '8080
D/RILJ    ( 1879): [0173]> SETUP_DATA_CALL 1 0 wapsfr   0 IP
I/RILV    ( 1473): processRequest: SETUP_DATA_CALL
I/RILV    ( 1473): requestSetupDataCall() selected new Connection ID (1) and Int
erface Name (rmnet0)
E/RILVAT  ( 1473): --- AT+CGDCONT=1,"ip","wapsfr",""
I/RILVAT  ( 1473): AT(12)> AT+CGDCONT=1,"ip","wapsfr",""
I/AT      ( 1520): request_set_PDP_context: -> request
I/AT      ( 1520): psccclient_iadb_set: Setting psccclient_iadb_field_use_rel_97
_qos to 0
I/AT      ( 1520): set_default_req_qos_parameters: Default qos for cid =1
I/AT      ( 1520): set_default_qos_2G_parameters: Default 2G qos for cid =1
E/RILVAT  ( 1473): --- AT*EIAAUW=1,1,"","",001,0
I/RILVAT  ( 1473): AT(12)> AT*EIAAUW=1,1,"","",001,0
I/AT      ( 1520): request_set_PDP_auth: EXE_STATE_REQUEST
E/RILVAT  ( 1473): --- AT*EPPSD=1,1,1
I/RILVAT  ( 1473): AT(12)> AT*EPPSD=1,1,1
I/AT      ( 1520): request_activate_PDP_context: EXE_STATE_REQUEST
I/AT      ( 1520): request_activate_PDP_context: connection id: 1 ignored
I/AT      ( 1520): add_client_tag_and_connid_to_request: (pscc): CT=446 connId=0

I/AT      ( 1520): exe_pscc_setup_data_call: EXE_STATE_SETUP_DATA_CALL_CREATE
I/AT      ( 1520): add_client_tag_and_connid_to_request: (pscc): CT=446 connId=1
000
I/AT      ( 1520): exe_pscc_setup_data_call: EXE_STATE_SETUP_DATA_CALL_SET
I/AT      ( 1520): add_client_tag_and_connid_to_request: (pscc): CT=446 connId=1
000
W/RIL PSCC( 1515): psccd_log_func: no successful response of aol configuration h
as been received, so aol might not work!
I/RIL_MAL ( 1515): GPDS_LIB::->GPDS_CONTEXT_ID_CREATE_REQ
W/RIL PSCC( 1515): psccd_log_func: state change: disconnected->connecting
I/AT      ( 1520): exe_pscc_setup_data_call: EXE_STATE_SETUP_DATA_CALL_CONNECT
I/RIL_MAL ( 1515): GPDS_LIB::entered gpds_lib_response_handler
I/RIL_MAL ( 1515): GPDS_LIB::<-GPDS_CONTEXT_ID_CREATE_RESP
I/RIL_MAL ( 1515): GPDS_LIB::PIPE state CREATED
I/RIL_MAL ( 1515): GPDS_LIB::->GPDS_LL_CONFIGURE_REQ
I/RIL_MAL ( 1515): GPDS_LIB::entered gpds_lib_response_handler
I/RIL_MAL ( 1515): GPDS_LIB::<-GPDS_CONTEXT_ID_CREATE_IND
I/RIL_MAL ( 1515): GPDS_LIB::entered gpds_lib_response_handler
I/RIL_MAL ( 1515): GPDS_LIB::<-GPDS_LL_CONFIGURE_RESP
I/RIL_MAL ( 1515): GPDS_LIB::Local link Config done to PLAIN mode
I/RIL_MAL ( 1515): GPDS_LIB::->GPDS_CONTEXT_CONFIGURE_REQ
I/RIL_MAL ( 1515): GPDS_LIB::entered gpds_lib_response_handler
I/RIL_MAL ( 1515): GPDS_LIB::<-GPDS_CONTEXT_CONFIGURE_RESP
I/RIL_MAL ( 1515): GPDS_LIB::PDP Context Configured
I/RIL_MAL ( 1515): GPDS_LIB::->GPDS_CONTEXT_ACTIVATE_REQ
I/RIL_MAL ( 1515): GPDS_LIB::entered gpds_lib_response_handler
I/RIL_MAL ( 1515): GPDS_LIB::<-GPDS_CONTEXT_ACTIVATING_IND
I/RIL_MAL ( 1515): GPDS_LIB::PDP Context Activating
W/RIL PSCC( 1515): psccd_log_func: pscc_bearer_event_activating
W/RIL PSCC( 1515): psccd_log_func: Sending event: pscc.message=event_connecting,
pscc.message_type=event,pscc.connid=1000
I/AT      ( 1520): psccclient_selector_callback_event: received event 26
I/AT      ( 1520): psccclient_selector_callback_event: CONNID Present
I/AT      ( 1520): psccclient_selector_callback_event: Setting event to record
I/AT      ( 1520): exe_pscc_setup_data_call: EXE_STATE_SETUP_DATA_CALL_CONNECTIN
G
I/RIL_MAL ( 1515): GPDS_LIB::entered gpds_lib_response_handler
I/RIL_MAL ( 1515): GPDS_LIB::<-GPDS_CONTEXT_ACTIVATE_RESP
I/RIL_MAL ( 1515): GPDS_LIB::msg id is GPDS_CONTEXT_ACTIVATE_RESP, hence not doi
ng proceed for activation
I/RIL_MAL ( 1515): GPDS_LIB::GPDS_Context Activate FAILED
I/RIL_MAL ( 1515): GPDS_LIB::Cause 21
I/RIL_MAL ( 1515): GPDS_LIB::PIPE disconnected
I/RIL_MAL ( 1515): GPDS_LIB::entered gpds_lib_response_handler
I/RIL_MAL ( 1515): GPDS_LIB::<-GPDS_CONTEXT_ACTIVATE_FAIL_IND
I/RIL_MAL ( 1515): GPDS_LIB::PDP Context Activation Failed
I/RIL_MAL ( 1515): GPDS_LIB::entered gpds_lib_response_handler
I/RIL_MAL ( 1515): GPDS_LIB::<-Unhandled MSG-ID 5a
I/RIL_MAL ( 1515): GPDS_LIB::entered gpds_lib_response_handler
I/RIL_MAL ( 1515): GPDS_LIB::<-GPDS_CONTEXT_STATUS_IND
I/RIL_MAL ( 1515): GPDS_LIB::PDP Context 0 Status
I/RIL_MAL ( 1515): GPDS_LIB::entered gpds_lib_response_handler
I/RIL_MAL ( 1515): GPDS_LIB::<-GPDS_CONTEXT_ID_DELETE_IND
I/RIL_MAL ( 1515): GPDS_LIB::PDP Context 0 Deleted
W/RIL PSCC( 1515): psccd_log_func: pscc_bearer_event_deactivated reason=1, cause
=33
W/RIL PSCC( 1515): psccd_log_func: state change: connecting->disconnected
W/RIL PSCC( 1515): psccd_log_func: Sending event: pscc.message=event_disconnecte
d,pscc.message_type=event,pscc.pdp_type=ipv4,pscc.reason=pdp_context_activation_
failed,pscc.cause=33,pscc.connid=1000
I/AT      ( 1520): psccclient_selector_callback_event: received event 29
I/AT      ( 1520): psccclient_selector_callback_event: CONNID Present
I/AT      ( 1520): psccclient_selector_callback_event: Setting event to record
I/AT      ( 1520): exe_pscc_setup_data_call: EXE_STATE_SETUP_DATA_CALL_DISCONNEC
TED
I/AT      ( 1520): add_client_tag_and_connid_to_request: (pscc): CT=446 connId=1
000
I/RIL_MAL ( 1515): GPDS_LIB::Removed pipe 33
I/AT      ( 1520): exe_pscc_setup_data_call: EXE_STATE_SETUP_DATA_CALL_DESTROY
I/AT      ( 1520): pscc_request_setup_data_call_scenario_1_step_12_13_14_receive
_pscc_destroy_response: executing in synchronous mode
E/AT      ( 1520): exe_check: Failure in file: vendor/st-ericsson/access_service
s/at/at_core_common/internal/executor/pscc/src/exe_pscc_requests.c       line: 5
52
E/AT      ( 1520): exe_check: Failure in file: vendor/st-ericsson/access_service
s/at/at_core_common/internal/executor/pscc/src/exe_pscc_requests.c       line: 3
292
E/AT      ( 1520): psccclient_selector_callback_request: request returned unsucc
essfully, failed!
E/RILVAT  ( 1473): --- AT+CEER
I/RILVAT  ( 1473): AT(12)> AT+CEER
I/AT      ( 1520): request_ceer: request_ceer
E/RILV    ( 1473): PDP Context Activate failed with SM Cause Code 33
D/RILV    ( 1473): requestSetupDataCall() errorhandler: Trying to remove account
 1
E/RILVAT  ( 1473): --- AT+CGDCONT=1
I/RILVAT  ( 1473): AT(12)> AT+CGDCONT=1
I/AT      ( 1520): request_set_PDP_context: -> request
D/RILV    ( 1473): requestSetupDataCall() errorhandler: Trying to unreserve list
 entry
D/RILJ    ( 1879): [0173]< SETUP_DATA_CALL error: com.android.internal.telephony
.CommandException: GENERIC_FAILURE
D/GSM     ( 1879): [GsmDataConnection-1] DcActivatingState msg.what=EVENT_SETUP_
DATA_CONNECTION_DONE
D/GSM     ( 1879): [GsmDataConnection-1] DataConnection Init failed com.android.
internal.telephony.CommandException: GENERIC_FAILURE
D/GSM     ( 1879): [GsmDataConnection-1] DataConnection setup result='Other erro
r' on cid=-1
D/RILJ    ( 1879): [0174]> LAST_DATA_CALL_FAIL_CAUSE
I/RILV    ( 1473): processRequest: LAST_DATA_CALL_FAIL_CAUSE
D/RILJ    ( 1879): [0174]< LAST_DATA_CALL_FAIL_CAUSE {33}
D/GSM     ( 1879): [GsmDataConnection-1] DcActivatingState msg.what=EVENT_GET_LA
ST_FAIL_DONE
D/GSM     ( 1879): [GsmDataConnection-1] DcInactiveState: setEnterNoticationPara
ms cp,cause
D/GSM     ( 1879): [GsmDataConnection-1] DcInactiveState: enter notifyConnectCom
pleted
D/GSM     ( 1879): [GsmDataConnection-1] notifyConnection at 1344278549550 cause
=Data Not subscribed
D/STK     ( 1879): BipProxy$DefaultBearerStateReceiver: onReceive(): Intent is :
  android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE
D/STK     ( 1879): BipProxy$DefaultBearerStateReceiver: BIP network state : CONN
ECTIVITY_ACTION disconnected
D/STK     ( 1879): BipProxy$DefaultBearerStateReceiver: onDisconnected
I/RILV    ( 1473): onUnsolicited: +CIEV: 2,96
I/RILV    ( 1473): onUnsolicited: +CIEV: 2,90
```

Maybe the problem is `PDP Context Activation Failed` ?

Comment: My service provider has three APNs. One for MMS, another for their own portal access called 'live' and the third for Internet access.  Only if the third is selected I am able to connect to Internet.  I am not sure why, sometimes my default APN is set to 'live' on start up and it results in breaking my head about the same problem. I accidentally found this and I had to manually switch to the third APN to make Internet to work. Check whether you have this problem.

Comment: @Narayana123@123.com There is only on internet connection APN and one MMS APN, but the MMS one can't be selected (this is normal I guess).

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the problem was actually wrong APN configuration. I configured the device using netowork operator automatic config mechanism, but turns out the parameters sent by the operator itself were wrong. Phone call to customer care solved the issue.